# C++ input from console, comparing integers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
bool choose() {
    int answer = 0;
    while(answer != 1 || answer != 2) {
        cout << endl << "Do you want to encrypt(enter 1) or decrypt(enter 2)?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
    }
    if(answer == 1) return true;
    return false;
}
```

What is the best way to read from line and compare input with integers?
I know ways `cin` , `gets` , `getline(cin, answer)` . 
Which should I use and why?

At the moment, this way is not working, because when i enter 1 or 2, it still stays in `while`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is a very good candidate for `do-while` loop, and if you use that you're not required to initialize the variable `answer`.

```
int answer; //= 0; no need to initialize!
do {

  cout<<"Do you want to encrypt(enter 1) or decrypt(enter 2)?"<<endl;
  cin >> answer;

}while(answer != 1 && answer != 2);
```

And of course, you need to use `&&` as others has already pointed out. :-)

By the way, what would happen if user entered any non-integer input such as `hgjkhg`? `cin>>answer` would fail to read the input and it will remain there forever, and the flag of `cin` will be set failure, and `cin` will not be able to read futher input. That means, the loop will never exit!

To avoid this, and to make the code more robust and complete you should write it as:

```
int answer = 0; 
while(answer != 1 && answer != 2) {

  cout<<"Do you want to encrypt(enter 1) or decrypt(enter 2)?"<<endl;
  if ( !(cin >> answer) )
  {
    cin.clear(); //clear the failure flag if there is an error when reading!
    std::string garbage;
    std::getline(cin, garbage); //read the garbage from the stream and throw it away
  }
}
```

Yes. You can use your `while` loop instead of `do-while`. All that you need to add the `if(!(cin>>answer)) { ... }` in your code. :-)

Comment: Now im not sure which to accept as answer, people answered my question earlier and exactly what i asked for, but you pointed out more stuff, which im very grateful for.

Comment: @Jaanus: Of course, you should accept mine :P.. because this code is is more robust and complete than what you've written. :-)

Comment: Oh and i did what you said, right, but when i enter word like `test` for input it starts running in the `DO` maniacally and does not even give me a new chance to enter anything..just prints out `Do you want to encrypt(enter 1) ........ ` infinately :/ PS! it also runs into the `if` cycle everytime, just without letting me input anything!

Comment: @Jaanus: Ohhh.. I didn't read the garbage from the stream, after `cin.clear()`. Anyway, now see my solution. Its correct now. Let me know if it works or not :-)

Comment: Hmm at first cin reads in my word and gets failure because it is string. Now you clear the flag, and then read in something from "somewhere"? I thought cin is for user input...

Comment: @Jaanus: Yes. `cin` is indeed for user-input (if by it you meant `stdin`). What happens here is that when you enter `test` as user-input, `cin >>answer` fails, because `answer` is `int` type, and `cin` cannot read a string into an int type. So it gets inside the `if` block where you first clear the failure flag which was set due to read-failure, and then you read the garbage which is still in the input stream, that garbage in this case is `test`; after reading the garbage, the input stream doesn't contain anything, and is ready for user-input again, to be read by `cin>>answer`. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2200/discussion-between-jaanus-and-nawaz)

Comment: If possible, can you come to chat?

Answer (score 10):

Your condition is incorrect. By [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you should be using `&&` instead.

```
while(answer != 1 && answer != 2) {
```

Comment: By DeMorgan's law, the other condition should be: `!(answer==1 || answer==2)`

Comment: Right, since you want to exit the loop if the variable has either of those values.

Answer (score 5):

You're reading the value correctly. However, the loop condition is wrong; it should be

```
while(answer != 1 && answer != 2)
```

Using `||` makes the condition always true, since no number is equal to both 1 and 2.